# How can i share apk file in my app (Share the apk file of the same app)

Tags: java, android

**App crashes while clicking button I made a simple app which share its apk file while clicked the button.
I want to implement it in my primary app but don't know whats the error**

```
package com.studenthelper.share;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button shr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        shr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
        shr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ApplicationInfo api = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
                String filePath = api.sourceDir;

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");

                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                        Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Using"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

log

```
2020-03-01 17:26:53.758 4741-4741/com.studenthelper.share E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.studenthelper.share, PID: 4741
    android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///data/app/com.studenthelper.share-s51_qOKFxmQ8bo6zuBgGow%3D%3D/base.apk exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1978)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2371)
        at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:963)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10228)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10234)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1669)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4590)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4548)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4909)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4877)
        at com.studenthelper.share.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6605)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6582)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2020-03-01 17:26:53.787 4741-4741/com.studenthelper.share I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4741 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

`android.os.FileUriExposedException` is raised for newer APIs because the file URI scheme of newer APIs is different than that of old APIs.

To solve this replace the below line of code:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
```

With:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, 
                    Uri.parse(filePath));
```